# Using Frida trace unable to attach and trace the calls

Tags: android, frida

I am new to Frida and trying to attach the method and some functions to my app. I am successfully able to work with Frida CLI.

I am running Frida server on my mobile and running below command for tracing:

```
frida-trace -U -i “Java_*” com.example.myapp
```

This just returns on my terminal and nothing gets printed. I call jni functions after this, still don't see any results. Am I missing anything. Kindly help.

Comment: Is your android phone rooted? AFAIK you can't run frida in a normal user context.

Comment: if you're running frida on a emulator and it uses arm translation frida-trace will not be able to find the loaded module